# Typeahead/bootstrap-tagsinput with MVC controller not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, typehead

I want to implement tag functionality in asp.net MVC I have took reference from "[Bootstrap Tags](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)". Below is the sample code which is working properly for me. As in URL I have passed static JSON file path.

```
    var citynames = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        //url: 'http://localhost:20182/Home/JsonData',
        url: '../Content/citynames.json',

        filter: function (list) {
            return $.map(list, function (cityname) {
                return { name: cityname };
            });
        }
    }
});
citynames.initialize();

var elt = $('.example_typeahead > > input');

elt.tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'cityname',
        displayKey: 'name',
        valueKey: 'name',
        source: citynames.ttAdapter()
    }});
```

But as soon as I changed in URL with my controller it won't work as below. I have just changed url with full url and with controller and action.

```
    prefetch: {
    url: 'http://localhost:20182/Home/JsonData',
    //url: '../Content/citynames.json',

    filter: function (list) {
        return $.map(list, function (cityname) {
            return { name: cityname };
        });
    }
}
```

My Action is as below

```
    public JsonResult JsonData()
    {
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/citynames.json"));
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Please let me know how could I pass json data using controller and action instead using static data from json file URL!!!

Comment: Sounds like `citynames.json` is already json, in which case, use `return Content(data)`

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke, wonderful it's working. Now I could understand concept of Content(data). But how could I mark your comment as answered and working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your 1st option works means that your `citynames.json` file is correctly formatted JSON, so there is no need to serialize it again using `return Json(data, ...);` (and if you did, then you would need to parse it back again using `JSON.parse()` in the script).

Instead, just return the data as a `ContentResult`

```
public ContentResult JsonData()
{
    var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/citynames.json"));
    return Content(data);

}
```